# Difference between two Struts filters?

Tags: struts2, filter, struts

I have seen two kinds of Struts 2 filters in *web.xml*.

1. `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher`
2. `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

Please give me difference between these two filters ?

Comment: If you are using Struts version >= 2.1.3, it’s always recommended to upgrade the new filter class – StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter).  See http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/difference-between-struts-2-filterdispatcher-and-strutsprepareandexecutefilter/

Comment: See: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/webxml.html.

Comment: I'd like to pull reasons from code but not near home computer... anyways StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter is the newer of the two. If you check in the same package there are also a prepare and a separate execute filter. This lets other components at the filter level interact with struts2 better. The prepare filter I think loads everything necessary for executing the action but does not kick off the execution. This lets 3rd party components interact with struts2 (I'm not creative enough to think of any use cases). The StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter is just a cut and paste of both these filers into

Comment: one class. So I'm pretty sure it's just simpler to maintain this one class and it's the reason FilterDispacher is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the new filter was introduced for the following reasons

1. There were a lot of issued with the `FilterDispatcher` and its deployment.
2. New Filter provides a better way to enable customizations and overrides.
3. Make it crystal clear to developers what filters are doing what 
   processes.
4. make dispatch process be more flexible to support things like native operation in OSGi or plugin system.

Out of them the main driving reasons was, earlier Filter dispatcher was having a lot of issues and other reason was to move towards OSGI.